# dark action bar with Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-source, android-theme

I am using `Theme.AppCompat` for my app to get the dark look. Everything looks good, except the action bar using this theme looks ancient i.e. it has a bright blue bottom divider.

I want the action bar to look like it is in `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Looking at [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml), i find :

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
       parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>


<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/appcompat_divider_dark</item>
</style>
```

So i create my own style as below :

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/appcompat_divider_dark</item>
</style>
```

But i get the build error :

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'actionBarDivider' with value 
 '@drawable/appcompat_divider_dark')
```

Why can't i use the same drawable that is being used by the framework?

Comment: Did you try `<item name="android:actionBarDivider">`?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes i have. It made no difference. Eclipse shows me the error is in the drawable resource reference, not in the attribute name, with or without the `android:`.

Comment: `@drawable/appcompat_divider_dark` means you have a resource named `appcompat_divider_dark.png` (or .9.png, or .jpg) in one of your `/res/drawable` folders. Is it so?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I do not have the drawable in my project, but i expect it to be available in the android framework, since it is being used by the `Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme. I checked the drawable folders of the support library project `appcompat_v7`, but could not find it there either. Not sure where it is hiding.

Comment: I used `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid</item>` instead and it worked. But this is available only on API 14 and above. I was hoping it to work for API 8 and above.

Comment: If you want to use an sdk resource, you have to: (if not usable) copy it from your sdk resource folder OR (if usable), use the `@android:drawable/drawable_name` syntax. If you want to support lower API levels (and I encourage you to), you have to use the **ActionBarCompat** themes, not the ActionBar ones! Something like: `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein that exactly is the issue i am facing. I am not able to find the `appcompat_divider_dark.png` resource anywhere. I have looked in my sdk folder as well as on `androidxref`. And yes, i am using only the AppCompat themes.

Comment: No, you didn't: "I used `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid</item>`" - This is not **AppCompat**, it's **ActionBar**

Comment: @FrankN.Stein That's wierd. I built and ran my app successfully with this attribute. Probably since i used it only in the `values-v14` folder, it does not result in an error when i run it on older APIs. Yes, i just confirmed that Eclipse shows me the error if i use this attribute in `values-v11` folder.

Comment: OK, I found `action_bar_divider`. It's **not a png** file, it's an **xml drawable**. There's only a vertical linear gradient, inside. On my PC, it's found in `C:\Program Files\[Eclipse installation Path]\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable`

Comment: I think you learned where to deep-look for "hidden" resources ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57152/discussion-between-faizal-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: Adding a picture might be better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue line is part of the background image used for the action bar. For example, you can find it in :  `sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ab_transparent_dark_holo.9.png`

The trick is to create your own Widget style by inheriting `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` and set the background attribute with your desired png, which does not have the blue line. I use the support library's existing`@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_dark_holo`. You can find it in the folder `sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/`.

So create the below element in the styles.xml file.

```
<style name="myActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_dark_holo</item>
</style>
```

Then include this newly created style in your theme(already present in the styles.xml file) :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>
</style>
```

To enable this change in older APIs, make the same changes in all 3 folder - `values-v14`, `values-v12` and `values`.
One important thing to note is that the "android:" namespace should not be used for the name attributes in the `values-v12` and `values` folders.